# Error while deploying my backend service on docker

Tags: docker

This is my first time using docker for deployment. I am trying to deploy a mern stack application and my structure of folder is like this.

- social_media_app

  - docke-compose.yml
  - social_media_frontend

    - dockerfile (for frontend)
    - all other code files
  - social_media_backend

    - dockerfile (for backend)
    - all other code files

Below are my code related to docker:

docker-compose.yml (file in social_media_app folder)

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./social_media_frontend
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./social_media_backend
    environment:
      - MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://Username:*****@cluster0.rl9zf.mongodb.net/Users?retryWrites=true&w=majority
    ports:
      - "3030:3030"
```

dockerfile (file in social_media_backend folder)

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR .

COPY package*.json ./

RUN rm -rf node_modules

RUN npm install

RUN npm uninstall bcrypt

RUN npm install bcrypt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3030

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

dockerfile (file in social_media_frontend folder)

```
FROM node:14 as build

WORKDIR .

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

package.json (for backend)

```
{
  "name": "social_media",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd social_media && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^4.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  }
}
```

Now when i try to run my docker image (using `docker-compose up -d` command) my frontend parts works well but i am have following error for my backend service:

```
social_media_app docker-compose logs backend
```

social_media_app-backend-1  | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1173
social_media_app-backend-1  |   return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
social_media_app-backend-1  |                  ^
social_media_app-backend-1  |
social_media_app-backend-1  | Error: Error loading shared library /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: Exec format error

[error for backend service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0rzE.png)

From error i felt it is about bcrypt version and so i tried to change version of bcrypt but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Please remove your username & password to connect to mongodb from the question (use something like `*****`).

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to contain a [mcve]?  Glancing at the image, it looks like it's a screen shot of a terminal window; please replace this with just plain text, and if the front-end component isn't required to demonstrate the issue, it's probably safe to remove that from the question.

Comment: It’s better to include the error as text in the question instead of link to the image (need to click to open it, unable to copy for searching)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Failed - bcrypt\_lib.node: Exec format error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72891468/docker-failed-bcrypt-lib-node-exec-format-error)

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743605/bcrypt-installation-fails-in-docker?rq=3