# Docker binding mountings are not recommended for local development of the web applications with server side?

Tags: node.js, docker

Everything has begun from [Why bcrypt (Node.js) package causes "Docker Failed - bcrypt_lib.node: Exec format error" while many other packages are not in the same conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77377715/4818123) issue. Although it seems to be something wrong with this Node.js package, it was many references to wrong organizing of Docker project structure.

> Please do not copy node_modules inside Docker. It decreases your build time and prevents this kind of errors from happening.
>
> https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/824#issuecomment-677485592

> The way you use docker containers is not recommended. Since you're using a stock docker container, you might as well just run node on the host.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/77386005/4818123

(By the way, what it the **stock docker container**?)

O'K, I am ready to rethink the organizing of my Docker project, but I will not reorganize it only because "everybody doing so" - I need to reach the deep understanding. The first question is what exactly wrong with my organizing? AFAIK what I am doing in `※` section is called **binding mounting** and it is the completely valid method of the exposing the files for the Docker container.

```yaml
version: "3.5"

services:

  FrontServer:

    image: node:18-alpine
    container_name: Example-Local-FrontServer
    ports: [ "8080:8080" ]

    # [ Theory ] Nodemon will not be found if invoke just "nodemon". See https://linuxpip.org/nodemon-not-found/
    # [ Theory ] About -L flag: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1802
    command: sh -c "cd var/www/example.com && node_modules/.bin/nodemon -L 03-LocalDevelopmentBuild/FrontServerEntryPoint.js --environment local"

    depends_on: [ Database ]

    # === ※ ================================================================
    volumes: 
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /var/www/example.com
    # =====================================================================

  Database:

    image: postgres
    container_name: Example-Local-Database
    ports: [ "${DATABASE_PORT}:${DATABASE_PORT}" ]

    environment:

      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"

    volumes:
      - DatabaseData:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  DatabaseData:
    name: Example-Local-DatabaseData
    driver: local
```

Please note that this preset is actual only for local development mode and does not related with production. The main difference between this modes is the incremental building.

- The **03-LocalDevelopmentBuild** directory is being *fully* generated - there is nothing that has been added there manually.
- The incremental building must work - the project build utility (based on Gulp + Webpack) must NOT be restarted manually each time when source file(s) has changed.

[image]

#### [ FAQ ] Why you need the "FrontServer" service in local development mode? You can use local Node.js as well

Because the local Node.js version could differ with one on the VPS, herewith could depend on specific project. AFAK the Docker has been designed *exactly* to solve this problem.

The only thing for which I use the local Node.js is the project building - for some reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Docker Compose file that sets up two services - one for a front server based on Node.js and another for a database based on Postgres.
The FrontServer service uses a [binding mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to map the current directory on the host to `/var/www/example.com` in the container. That allows the service to access the files in that directory and serves as a way to develop locally while having the code run within a Docker container.

```bash
+--------------+      +------------------+      +---------------------+
|   Host OS    |      | Docker Container |      | Mounted Directory   |
|              | <--> | (FrontServer)    | <--> | (example.com files) |
+----------+---+      +------------------+      +---------------------+
           |                                       
           |
           |                             +------------------+
           |                             | Docker Container |
           +---------------------------> | (Database)       |
                                         +------------------+
```

A possible issue is the binding mount of the entire project directory, including the `node_modules` folder.
When Node.js dependencies are installed, the binaries are often compiled for the specific system architecture they are being installed on. If the host machine and the Docker container have different architectures or different versions of system libraries, hence the problem you have with `bcrypt`.

Instead of bind-mounting the `node_modules` directory, or, as in [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77408742/6309), moving the Node.js environment entirely to the host system, you could have Docker install the dependencies during the image `build` stage.
That would make sure the correct architecture binaries are used. Update your [Docker Compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) and create a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) for your FrontServer service:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /var/www/example.com
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
CMD ["node", "03-LocalDevelopmentBuild/FrontServerEntryPoint.js"]
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yaml
...
services:
  FrontServer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    # rest of the service definition
```

That would guarantee architecture consistency while providing flexibility in how you manage your Node.js environment and dependencies.
The dependencies would be installed within the Docker container that is based on the specified Node.js image (`node:18-alpine`).
Meaning: the `node_modules` directory is created in an environment that matches the one where the application will be running, which eliminates potential architecture mismatch issues.
And this allows for a clean separation between the host and container environments, which is useful if there are multiple developers working on the project with varying local setups.

By defining the project in a `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yaml`, you are codifying the environment project, making it easy to share, replicate, and version control. However, this may add a level of indirection when compared to running Node.js directly on the host, which could potentially make certain tasks more cumbersome.

---

A [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) could enhance the setup by optimizing the image build process, especially if there are intermediate build steps or tools required that are not needed in the final image.

For example, if your project requires a build step with tools like a bundler or a compiler, a multi-stage build can help keep those tools out of the final image, reducing the image size and minimizing the attack surface.

```
# Build Stage
FROM node:18-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /var/www/example.com
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
RUN npm run build  # Assuming there is a build script in package.json

# Runtime Stage
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /var/www/example.com
COPY --from=build /var/www/example.com .
CMD ["node", "03-LocalDevelopmentBuild/FrontServerEntryPoint.js"]
```

The build stage is defined where dependencies are installed, and the application is built.
Then, a second stage is defined for running the application, where the built assets from the first stage are copied over. That results in a smaller final image as only the necessary files are included.

---

As noted by [Elvis Adomnica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3415496/elvis-adomnica) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77407879/docker-binding-mountings-are-not-recommended-for-local-development-of-the-web-ap/77425098#comment136554553_77425098):

> I think you might need to mention a `.dockerignore` file due to this copy `COPY . .`

True: the addition of a [`.dockerignore` file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) is indeed an important aspect to consider, particularly in the context of Docker builds.

A `.dockerignore` file functions similarly to a `.gitignore` file. It tells Docker which files and directories to ignore when copying files into the Docker image with `COPY` commands in the Dockerfile. This can include directories like `node_modules`, `logs`, or any other files that are not necessary for the Docker image, such as local configuration files, temporary files, or files that are generated during runtime.

The `docker build` command sends the entire **context** (all the files and directories located in the same directory as the Dockerfile, by default) to the Docker daemon. Including unnecessary files can significantly increase the size of this build context, leading to longer build times.

Particularly relevant to Node.js projects, if `node_modules` is not included in `.dockerignore`, the local `node_modules` directory could overwrite the one in the container created during the build process (due to `RUN npm ci` or `RUN npm install`). This could lead to architecture mismatches if the host and container environments are different.

And excluding sensitive files or directories ensures they are not inadvertently included in the Docker image, which could be a security risk if the image is shared or deployed.

You find those explanations and more in "[How to use `.dockerignore` and its importance](https://shisho.dev/blog/posts/how-to-use-dockerignore/)" (Dec. 2021).

A good `.dockerignore` file to add in your case:

```
node_modules
npm-debug.log
Dockerfile
.dockerignore
.git
.gitignore
README.md
LICENSE
*.md
```

As explained above, `node_modules` is ignored to prevent the local directory from being added to the Docker context and potentially overwriting the container's `node_modules` directory. Other files like logs, documentation, and version control directories are also excluded.

```bash
+--------------+      +------------------+      +---------------------+
|   Host OS    |      | Docker Container |      | Mounted Directory   |
|              | <--> | (FrontServer)    | <--> | (example.com files) |
+----------+---+      +------------------+      +---------------------+
           |           | (Excludes files |
           |           |  specified in   |
           |           |  .dockerignore) |
           |           +-----------------+
           |
           |                             +------------------+
           |                             | Docker Container |
           +---------------------------> | (Database)       |
                                         +------------------+
```

---

There are some addition issues that must be solved.
Are symlinks like `"@yamato-daiwa/automation": "../../Development/YamatoDaiwaAutomation"` in `package.json` will work? (I know that such links are not sharable, but it is only for the debugging of the project building system, in my case - `@yamato-daiwa/automation`).
I suppose, it will not work, but is there the solution?

The use of symlinks in `package.json`, particularly for local packages like `"@yamato-daiwa/automation": "../../Development/YamatoDaiwaAutomation"`, can be tricky in a Dockerized environment.
The symlink works fine on your host system, but when running inside a Docker container, the file path it points to (`../../Development/YamatoDaiwaAutomation`) might not exist or be accessible in the same way.

- The Docker container has its own filesystem separate from the host. A relative path that makes sense on your host machine may not be valid inside the container.
- If the symlink points to a directory outside the Docker context or not mounted as a volume in the container, it will not be accessible.

You might consider instead mounting the target directory of the symlink as a **volume** in your Docker container. That would make the directory accessible at the expected path inside the container.
However, this approach can become cumbersome if you have multiple such dependencies or if the paths vary significantly.

```yaml
# docker-compose.yaml
...
volumes:
    - type: bind
    source: /absolute/path/to/Development/YamatoDaiwaAutomation
    target: /path/inside/container
```

Or, instead of relying on filesystem symlinks, you can use `npm link` or `yarn link` to create a symlink. That method is more package-manager aware and might handle some of the path resolution issues more gracefully. However, it requires additional setup steps and may still face issues with Docker's separate filesystem.

As part of your Docker build process, you could copy the local package directly into the container and reference it as if it was a part of the project. That approach ensures the package is present in the container's filesystem but requires you to rebuild the Docker image for any changes in the local package.

The general idea remains: if the symlink is for development or debugging purposes, consider if there is a different approach that could achieve the same goal without relying on symlinks. For instance, publishing a development version of the package to a private npm registry or using feature branches.

Comment: I think you might need to mention a `.dockerignore` file due to this copy `COPY . .`

Comment: @ElvisAdomnica I agree, and I have edited the answer to add some explanation on that.

Comment: Thank you for the great lecture. It is unlikely that somebody will post the better answer, so I'll accept your answer and give you the prize. I have understood which direction to I should move, but there are some addition issues that must be solved. First: are symlinks like `"@yamato-daiwa/automation": "../../Development/YamatoDaiwaAutomation",` in `package.json` will work? (I know that such links are not sharable, but it is only for the debugging of the project building system, in my case - `@yamato-daiwa/automation`). I suppose, it will not work, but is there the solution?

Comment: @TakeshiTokugawaYD I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 1):

With the setup you show, you can also

```bash
brew install nodejs           # or similarly install Node on your host system (once)
docker-compose up -d Database # only if the database shuts down
npm install                   # probably just once
nodemon                       # as needed
```

and things will work as expected.  You don't need to figure out the Compose configuration, look up "bind mount" terminology, research the `nodemon -L` option, or ask Stack Overflow why filesystem synching isn't working.  Many of the questions I see in this space already have an array of host-based tools like an IDE and the Docker Desktop application, and there's no particular reason to run the Node interpreter in a container while the rest of the stack is on the host.

More broadly, I tend to recommend against bind mounts (or any sort of volume mounts) that inject the application source code into a container.  If you're planning to use Docker as part of an eventual deployment system, then the bind mount hides what's actually in the image, and you'll be deploying an untested image.  I've also seen problems where the Dockerfile does additional setup that gets hidden by a bind mount, or where the wrong directory gets mounted, and things mysteriously stop working.  Just removing the bind mount entirely avoids this class of problem.

---

The `bcrypt` issue you describe can result if you're using a Linux container on a non-Linux host.  In this case, the `node_modules` directory is different if you're running a process in a container or on the host, and bind-mounting the host's source tree into the container you can't keep the wrong-architecture `node_modules` from coming along.

The [usual workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181032/add-a-volume-to-docker-but-exclude-a-sub-folder) is to use an *anonymous volume* to tell Docker that the `node_modules` directory is actually user data that needs to be preserved between runs, and take advantage of a copy-on-first-use behavior.  This also means that Docker will completely ignore changes in the `package.json` file even if you rebuild the image, and it can mean the application's behavior is dependent on what this machine's `node_modules` volume contains.  This reintroduces the "works on my machine" problem that Docker generally tries to avoid.

You should in fact use a `.dockerignore` file to avoid copying the host's `node_modules` directory into the image; but on the flip side, your Dockerfile should generally `RUN npm ci` to create its own correct-environment `node_modules` directory based on your `package-lock.json` file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You have taught a lot of information, and I'll study it. However, why I can not accept the usage of local Node.js (for the serving of the web application) is the version of the local Node.js could differ with the production one.

Comment: I've almost never had that be a practical problem with Node, or most other languages, up to major versions of the language.  Version managers like `nvm` do exist that can work around that problem without introducing the full filesystem isolation that's a Docker core feature.

Comment: O'K thank you again. Your answer has very good quality, but because this topics is very important, I'll start the bounty to get some additional information and/or alternative opinions. Maybe you will be the winner.